# Cannot compile with libssh2

Tags: c++, c, linux, ssh, libssh2

I downloaded and installed the latest [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.4.0.tar.gz) from their [website](http://www.libssh2.org/) into the location `/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0`

I was trying to build one of the example programs [(ssh2.c)](http://www.libssh2.org/examples/ssh2.html) that is available in the example directory. When I compiled with `make` from `/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/example` as

```
make ssh2
```

, it compiled and ran quite fine. I then copied the program `ssh2.c` to a different path `(~/Projects/precious/)` and issued the command

```
gcc -g -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/include -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src/obj ssh.c -o ssh -lssh2 -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lcrypto -lssl -lz
```

When I am trying to run  the program, it greets me with the following message

```
./ssh: symbol lookup error: ./ssh: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_handshake
```

I also tried to compile it simply as

```
g++ -g ssh.c -o ssh -lssh2
```

The response is all the same.

I also tried compiling as

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H      -g -O2  -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/include -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src/obj -c -o ssh.o ssh.c 
libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o ssh  ssh.o /usr/local/lib/libssh2.la
```

but without any luck. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your libssh2 package that you've built by hand is a different version (probably newer) than the one installed on your system.  And your link line is trying to use the one installed on the system, which doesn't have the `libssh2_session_handshake` function in it.  Try this line:

```
gcc -g -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/include -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src/obj ssh.c -o ssh -lssh2 -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lcrypto -lssl -lz
```

or maybe this one:

```
gcc -g -L/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src/obj -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/include -I/usr/src/libssh2-1.4.0/src/obj ssh.c -o ssh -lssh2 -ldl -lnsl -lresolv -lcrypto -lssl -lz
```

The important thing is to get the -L flag pointing to the path where your compiled library is located.